# selenium dynamic value - for textbox

Tags: css, xpath, selenium, selenium-ide

I am in the middle of building a test case, where i came across this problem. In my web page there exists a search text box. I have recorded the web page using selenium ide.

```
type  | id=search_input_char_name_136 | myproduct     // textbox for search
click | css=button.oe_button          | -            // search icon click
```

I got the above code by recording, here in "type" action an id value is show for textbox, when i use the same value while testing, `id not found error` occurs. so i have recorded  the action again and i found id is dynamic. for each time the id keeps on changing.

i have googled it and found xpath will be solution for this. i am very new to selenium and xpath. i couldn't figure out the solution. so help to slove this.. provide me the xpath syntax to type=id of search-textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the selenium IDE itself, after the recording is finished, try to click the drop down named `Target` in the IDe window for this textbox. There, in that drop down, you can get various locators like xpath, name, css, dom etc. Observe, which one is static for all the recordings and use that locator. Hope it helps. Let me know if you are still struck with this issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it worked. xpath:position was static in all recordings i have used it and tested it works fine.